# STS, Buildship 2.x and annotation processor

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-jdt, buildship

I installed STS 3.8.4, created a Spring poject starter of type Gradle (Buildship 2.x) and I can observed that the Eclipse annotation processor not working. The spring-boot-configuration-processor is not recognized, is this normal ? Thanks

Comment: I solved my problem by using Gradle plugin gradle-apt-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is normal. In fact it is amongst the known limitations of the BuildShip plugins.

See: https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/wiki/Migration-guide-from-STS-Gradle-to-Buildship

Under: "Features only supported by STS Gradle"

> Annotation processing: The JDT annotation processor is configured when the spring-boot-configration-processor is present on a project's classpath.